# Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap error with templated class

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class HIDValue{
private:

    void* mValue;
    UINT mSize;
    HIDElement mElement;

public:
    HIDValue() {
        mValue = 0;
        mSize = 0;
    }

    template <class T>
    HIDValue(T pValue, HIDElement pElement) {
        mElement = pElement;
        mValue = 0;
        setValue(pValue);
    }

    HIDValue(const HIDValue& pValue) {
        mSize = pValue.mSize;
        mElement = pValue.mElement;
        mValue = 0;
        if(mSize) {
            mValue = new char[mSize];
            memcpy(mValue, pValue.mValue, mSize);
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void setValue(T pValue) {
        if(mValue)
            delete mValue;

        mValue = new T;
        *((T*)mValue) = *((T*)&pValue);
        mSize = sizeof(T);
    }

    ~HIDValue() {
                //THE MENTIONED ERROR IS HERE
        if(mValue)
            delete mValue;
    }

    void setElement(HIDElement pElement) {
        mElement = pElement;
    }

    const HIDElement& getElement() const {
        return mElement;
    }

    template <class T>
    bool getValue(T* pValue) const {
        if(mValue && mSize <= sizeof(T)) {  
            *pValue = *((T*)mValue);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

With some changes it's working fine:

```
class HIDValue{
private:

    //void* mValue;
    char mValue[16];
    UINT mSize;
    HIDElement mElement;

public:
    HIDValue() {
        //mValue = 0;
        mSize = 0;
    }

    template <class T>
    HIDValue(T pValue, HIDElement pElement) {
        mElement = pElement;
        //mValue = 0;
        setValue(pValue);
    }

    HIDValue(const HIDValue& pValue) {
        mSize = pValue.mSize;
        mElement = pValue.mElement;
        //mValue = 0;
        if(mSize) {
            //mValue = new char[mSize];
            memcpy(mValue, pValue.mValue, mSize);
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void setValue(T pValue) {
        //if(mValue)
        //  delete mValue;

        //mValue = new T;
        *((T*)mValue) = *((T*)&pValue);
        mSize = sizeof(T);
    }

    ~HIDValue() {
        //itten egy hiba vala
        //if(mValue)
        //  delete mValue;
    }

    void setElement(HIDElement pElement) {
        mElement = pElement;
    }

    const HIDElement& getElement() const {
        return mElement;
    }

    template <class T>
    bool getValue(T* pValue) const {
        if(mValue && mSize <= sizeof(T)) {  
            *pValue = *((T*)mValue);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

I am curious what is the reason of the error.

Thanks ahead and sorry for my english!

Comment: Can you please include the entire error message?

Comment: ggered a breakpoint
HEAP[....exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002C0000, 002C3768 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ....exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ....exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `void*`. You want to use Boost.Any or Boost.Variant (latter if the set of allowed types is to be restricted).
2. Don't use `memcpy`. It's likely to not work correctly with UDTs.
3. Don't use C-style casts.

The error is most likely related to the fact that you're deleting `void*` instead of `T*`.

Comment: Then I'll make templated the whole class.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete a pointer of type void which can cause many problems. Also, when you delete a void pointer the destructors of the mValue don't fire because the type of the object is unknown.